# Can graphql codegen automatically generate types for hooks' result data field?

Tags: typescript, graphql, codegen

I'm using graphql codegen hooks, which results are of the type: `ApolloReactCommon.QueryResult`, meaning it's an object that has `data`, `loading` and `error` fields.

Most generally, I'll use the `data` in other components, where I need to define its type. I currently need to write something like this to get `data` type:

```js
type MyPost = MyPostQueryHookResult['data']
```

I would have expected to get this `MyPost` type created for me. Is there a way to have it generated automatically?

My config:

```
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
    config:
      withHooks: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use fragments when building the query. Types will be generated for each fragment and they can then be used directly.

source: [from the main contributor of graphql-codegen](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/2977)

Comment: The owner didn't say which is the best way. It's more like your choice. Personally, I'm against using fragments because it's more complex. Using bridges is more convenient.